# How to pause and resume text into text to speech

Tags: android, text-to-speech, pause, resume

I'm working on text to speech app in which I'm translate the text into different languages with highlight the text now I want to pause and resume the highlighted text. I have use the stop function but it stop the text to speech engine when I want to resume text it starts from the start.

---

**Here is my Code**

```
    package com.nextsuntech.texttospeech;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.speech.tts.UtteranceProgressListener;
import android.text.Spannable;
import android.text.SpannableString;
import android.text.Spanned;
import android.text.style.BackgroundColorSpan;
import android.text.style.ForegroundColorSpan;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton;
import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText;
import com.google.firebase.ml.common.modeldownload.FirebaseModelDownloadConditions;
import com.google.firebase.ml.naturallanguage.FirebaseNaturalLanguage;
import com.google.firebase.ml.naturallanguage.translate.FirebaseTranslateLanguage;
import com.google.firebase.ml.naturallanguage.translate.FirebaseTranslator;
import com.google.firebase.ml.naturallanguage.translate.FirebaseTranslatorOptions;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Spinner fromSP;
    Spinner toSP;
    TextInputEditText sourceText;
    ImageView micIV;
    ImageView pauseBT;
    ImageView playBT;
    MaterialButton translationBT;
    TextView translationTV;
    ImageView speakTextIV;
    TextToSpeech textToSpeech;

    String[] fromLanguages = {"From", "English", "Arabic", "Urdu", "Hindi", "German", "Chinese", "Spanish"
            , "French", "Bengali", "Russian", "Portuguese"};
    String[] toLanguages = {"To", "English", "Arabic", "Urdu", "Hindi", "German", "Chinese", "Spanish"
            , "French", "Bengali", "Russian", "Portuguese"};

    private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSION_CODE = 1;
    int fromLanguageCode, toLanguageCode = 0;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        fromSP = findViewById(R.id.idFromSpinner);
        toSP = findViewById(R.id.idToSpinner);
        sourceText = findViewById(R.id.idEditSource);
        micIV = findViewById(R.id.idIVMic);
        translationBT = findViewById(R.id.idBtnTranslation);
        translationTV = findViewById(R.id.idTranslatedTV);
        speakTextIV = findViewById(R.id.iv_speak_text);
        pauseBT = findViewById(R.id.bt_pause);
        playBT = findViewById(R.id.bt_play);


        fromSP.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                fromLanguageCode = getLanguageCode(fromLanguages[i]);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });

        ArrayAdapter fromAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.spinner_item, fromLanguages);
        fromAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        fromSP.setAdapter(fromAdapter);


        toSP.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                toLanguageCode = getLanguageCode(toLanguages[i]);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });


        ArrayAdapter toAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.spinner_item, toLanguages);
        toAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        toSP.setAdapter(toAdapter);


        micIV.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Say something to translate");
                try {
                    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_PERMISSION_CODE);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        translationBT.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                translationTV.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
                translationTV.setText("");
                if (sourceText.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please enter text to translate", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (fromLanguageCode == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please select source language", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (toLanguageCode == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please select the language to translate", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    translateText(fromLanguageCode, toLanguageCode, sourceText.getText().toString());
                }
            }
        });
        //pause the tts engine and text
        pauseBT.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (textToSpeech.isSpeaking()) {
                    playBT.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void translateText(int fromLanguageCode, int toLanguageCode, String source) {
        translationTV.setText("Downloading mode, Please waite");
        FirebaseTranslatorOptions options = new FirebaseTranslatorOptions.Builder()
                .setSourceLanguage(fromLanguageCode)
                .setTargetLanguage(toLanguageCode)
                .build();

        FirebaseTranslator translator = FirebaseNaturalLanguage.getInstance().getTranslator(options);
        FirebaseModelDownloadConditions conditions = new FirebaseModelDownloadConditions.Builder().build();
        translator.downloadModelIfNeeded(conditions).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void unused) {
                translationTV.setText("Translation...");
                translator.translate(source).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(String s) {
                        translationTV.setText(s);
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed to translate, Please try agian", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed to download model, Check your internet connection.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_PERMISSION_CODE) {
            ArrayList<String> result = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            sourceText.setText(result.get(0));
        }
    }

    //String[] toLanguages = {"To", "English", "Arabic", "Urdu", "Hindi", "German","Chines ","Spanish"
    //,"French","Bengali","Russian","Portuguese "};

    private int getLanguageCode(String language) {

        int languageCode = 0;
        if ("English".equals(language)) {
            languageCode = FirebaseTranslateLanguage.EN;
        } else if ("Arabic".equals(language)) {
            languageCode = FirebaseTranslateLanguage.AR;
        } else if ("Urdu".equals(language)) {
            languageCode = FirebaseTranslateLanguage.UR;
        } else if ("German".equals(language)) {
            languageCode = FirebaseTranslateLanguage.GA;
        } else if ("Hindi".equals(language)) {
            languageCode = FirebaseTranslateLanguage.HI;
        } else if ("Chinese".equals(language)) {
            languageCode = FirebaseTranslateLanguage.ZH;
        } else if ("Spanish".equals(language)) {
            languageCode = FirebaseTranslateLanguage.ES;
        } else if ("French".equals(language)) {
            languageCode = FirebaseTranslateLanguage.FR;
        } else if ("Bengali".equals(language)) {
            languageCode = FirebaseTranslateLanguage.BN;
        } else if ("Russian".equals(language)) {
            languageCode = FirebaseTranslateLanguage.RU;
        } else if ("Portuguese".equals(language)) {
            languageCode = FirebaseTranslateLanguage.PT;
        }

        speakTextIV.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onInit(int i) {
                        String text = translationTV.getText().toString();
                        if (text.isEmpty()) {
                            translationTV.setError("Please enter text to speech!");
                        } else {
                            pauseBT.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            if (language.equals("English")) {
                                textToSpeech.setLanguage(new Locale("EN"));
                                textToSpeech.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null, "UNIQUE_UTTERANCE_ID");
                            } else if (language.equals("Arabic")) {
                                textToSpeech.setLanguage(new Locale("ar-sa"));
                                textToSpeech.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, "UNIQUE_UTTERANCE_ID");
                            } else if (language.equals("Urdu")) {
                                textToSpeech.setLanguage(new Locale("UR"));
                                textToSpeech.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, "UNIQUE_UTTERANCE_ID");
                            } else if (language.equals("Hindi")) {
                                textToSpeech.setLanguage(new Locale("HI"));
                                textToSpeech.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, "UNIQUE_UTTERANCE_ID");
                            } else if (language.equals("German")) {
                                textToSpeech.setLanguage(new Locale("DE"));
                                textToSpeech.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, "UNIQUE_UTTERANCE_ID");
                            } else if (language.equals("Chinese")) {
                                textToSpeech.setLanguage(new Locale("ZH"));
                                textToSpeech.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, "UNIQUE_UTTERANCE_ID");
                            } else if (language.equals("Spanish")) {
                                textToSpeech.setLanguage(new Locale("ES"));
                                textToSpeech.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, "UNIQUE_UTTERANCE_ID");
                            } else if (language.equals("French")) {
                                textToSpeech.setLanguage(new Locale("AF"));
                                textToSpeech.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, "UNIQUE_UTTERANCE_ID");
                            } else if (language.equals("Bengali")) {
                                textToSpeech.setLanguage(new Locale("BN"));
                                textToSpeech.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, "UNIQUE_UTTERANCE_ID");
                            } else if (language.equals("Russian")) {
                                textToSpeech.setLanguage(new Locale("RU"));
                                textToSpeech.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, "UNIQUE_UTTERANCE_ID");
                            } else if (language.equals("Portuguese")) {
                                textToSpeech.setLanguage(new Locale("PT"));
                                textToSpeech.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, "UNIQUE_UTTERANCE_ID");
                            }

                        }
                    }
                });

                textToSpeech.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(new UtteranceProgressListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onStart(String utteranceId) {
                        Log.i("TTS", "utterance started");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onDone(String utteranceId) {
                        Log.i("TTS", "utterance done");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(String utteranceId) {
                        Log.i("TTS", "utterance error");
                    }


                    @Override
                    public void onRangeStart(String utteranceId, int start, int end, int frame) {
                        // onRangeStart (and all UtteranceProgressListener callbacks) do not run on main thread
                        // ... so we explicitly manipulate views on the main thread:
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                String translate = translationTV.getText().toString();
                                Spannable textWithHighlights = new SpannableString(translate);

                                textWithHighlights.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.YELLOW), start, end, Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
                                translationTV.setText(textWithHighlights);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }

        });
        return languageCode;
    }

}
```

Please guide me how to stop the speaking text in tts engine and resume the text

Answer (score 0):

been there, did that, you can't pause and resume text to speech...

but there is a workaround - split your `text` into sentences and play them sequentially, start next one when [`OnUtteranceCompletedListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech?hl=en#setOnUtteranceCompletedListener(android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnUtteranceCompletedListener)) fire and obviously track index which sentence is currently played. when user stop TTS then "really" stop it, but when user resume then start reading from sentence, which was read at the moment of pausing (stored index will help)

sadly I don't have access to this code, so I can't provide any useful snippet, but I remember that it was a lot work to do (I've even added action buttons on notification for jumping over next/prev paragraph, as my TTS was reading some articles in background `Service`, user may leave app/gui)

Comment: Ok thank for your time. first I will split my text into sentences